# How to use AmazonDynamoDB Local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How do i make user of AmazonDynamoDB Local work for me. In spite of providing all the configuration information i get error on server side and client timeouts.

---

### Server

---

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>java -Djava.library.path=. -jar C:\Users\XXX\XXX\DynamoDB\dynamodb_loca
l_2013-09-12\DynamoDBLocal.jar --port 8888
2013-10-09 11:15:44.346:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2013-10-09 11:15:44.413:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Oct 09, 2013 11:15:55 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
INFO: [sqlite] DB[1]: instantiated [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_us-east-1.db]
Oct 09, 2013 11:15:55 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] cannot open DB[1]: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.Unsa
tisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-win32-x86 in java.library.path
Oct 09, 2013 11:15:55 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
SEVERE: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[AKIAIZR4RBNLFYSQQKAQ_us-east-1.db]: error running job queue
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-win3
2-x86 in java.library.path
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1314)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:258)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:269)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.openConnection(SQLiteQueue.java:464)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:641)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-win32-x86 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:349)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
    at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)
    ... 9 more

```
Oct 09, 2013 11:15:55 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
WARNING: [sqlite] SQLiteQueue[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_us-east-1.db]: stopped abnormally, reincarnating in 3000ms
```

---

### Client

---

```
class Program
{
    private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateClient();

        CreateTablesUploadSampleItems(client);
    }

    private static void CreateClient()
    {
        var config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
        config.ServiceURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceURL"];
        var accessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
        var secretAccessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(accessKey, secretAccessKey, config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the java command so that `-Djava.library.path` refers to the path under which you extracted the Local DynamoDB package. The `.` in `-Djava.library.path=.` means "the current directory", and the app needs to be able to load the native SQLite libraries in the Local DynamoDB directory.

So you can either run this command from within the local DynamoDB directory:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

or you have to give the full path to both:

```
java -Djava.library.path=c:\path\to\dynamodb\ -jar c:\path\to\dynamodb\DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

## IntelliJ

If you're running a configuration in IntellJ, you can add the jar using the dialog *Edit Configurations | Modify Options | Modify classpath*, and add the path to the jar there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Maven plugin, that does all this magic for you: http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamodb-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: hi yegor256, first of all thanks for your response. sorry but im not familiar with Java or JRE. The above example is based on .NET SDK and haven't got a any experience with Maven. Can you please suggest me a .NET sample that i can use to work with DynamoDB Local.

Thanks for your help in advance.
Pavan

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old request but since then I have started using other solution such as localstack. I recommend engineers to use [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). It can be run by invoking a docker!